# url regex not working for localhost in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, regex

My code is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //bit_url function
    function bit_url(url)
    {
        var url=url;
        var username="username"; // bit.ly username
        var key="bit.ly API key";
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten",
            data:{longUrl:url,apiKey:key,login:username},
            dataType:"jsonp",
            success:function(v)
            {
                var bit_url=v.data.url;
                $("#result").html('<a href="'+bit_url+'" target="_blank">'+bit_url+'</a>');
            }
        });
    }

    $("#short").click(function()
    {
        var url=$("#url").val();
        var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
        var urltest=urlRegex.test(url);
        if(urltest)
        {
            bit_url(url);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Bad URL");
        }
    });
});
</script>

//HTML Code
<input type="text" name="url" id="url"/>
<input type="submit" id="short" value="Submit"/>
<div id="result"></div>`enter code here`
```

when I am giving [this url](http://localhost:3000/users/new) then its neither giving error nor its giving short url. Please help me out to find the way to come out with this error.

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bit.ly does not encode `localhost` URLs any more - [see this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bitly-api/ZRcLndyWWTQ)

Comment: Thank's. Is there any other way  for short url other than bit.ly which supports _localhost_